# CakePHP - how to make full names in specific formats

Tags: cakephp

Hi I'm trying to get cake to show full names in archival standards. I need the names to be shown in the format of "LASTNAME Firstname", with lastname being all caps and the first letter of first name in caps. I have in my model first_name and last_name and have managed to combine them via virtual field, but am having problems with the two different caps mods.

Please and thank you.

Comment: Why not just formatting on output? (echo)

Answer (score 0):

in your afterfind callback: strtoupper(lastname) and  ucfirst(strtolower($firstname))
or you could do this in your beforesave and save the fields like this in your database.

or as suggested by mark: why not just do this in your views?

Answer (score 0):

```
public $virtualFields = array(
   'vf_full_name' => 'CONCAT(UPPER(`last_name`), " ", UPPER(SUBSTRING(`first_name`, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(`first_name`, 2)))',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your view. Saving your data in the database in this format will just lead to headaches in the future. For example, if you save the surname “DiMaggio” in the all-uppercase format (“DIMAGGIO”) you can’t then just convert it to all-lowercase and capitalize the first letter; that gives you “Dimaggio” which is wrong.

As I say, just do it in your view. First name and last name are separate, which is great.

```
<p class="name">
  <span class="last-name"><?php echo h($user['User']['last_name']); ?></span>,
  <span class="first-name"><?php echo h($user['User']['first_name']); ?></span>
</p>
```

I’d also convert the last name to uppercase which CSS rather than HTML, which is more semantic.

```
.last-name {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

It’s easier to change a CSS rule than to go through view files and remove strings wrapped in `strtoupper()` function calls.